# code=exited, status=203/EXEC on Linux service (dotnet Application)

Tags: asp.net, linux, ubuntu, service

I'm trying to load a dotnet application on Device boot,
and I created this configuration file for my custom service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Horidesk

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/horidesk/publish
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /home/ubuntu/horidesk/publish/Horidesk.dll
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
User=www-data
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But when I start this one I got this error:

```
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/horidesk.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-07-21 22:19:10 CEST; 4s ago
    Process: 4848 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /home/ubuntu/horidesk/publish/Horidesk.dll (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
   Main PID: 4848 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
```

How can I fix this? Thanks